# "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foo;isOutput=true] doesn't work in ${{ each }} loop

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are getting very weird behaviour from Azure Devops YAML pipelines while trying to foreach loop with variables.

code:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: StageA
    displayName: "Stage A"
    pool: DefaultPool
    jobs:
      - job: StageA
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - task: PowerShell@2
            name: bla
            displayName: "Set Vars"
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varlist;isOutput=true]value1,value2"

  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: "Deploy"
    dependsOn: StageA
    variables:
      varlist: $[stageDependencies.StageA.outputs['bla.varlist']]
    jobs:
      - deployment: "Deploy"
        environment:
          name: "Production"
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
          tags: APP
        strategy:
          rolling:
            maxParallel: 100
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  displayName: "give output"
                  inputs:
                    targetType: "inline"
                    script: |
                      Write-Host "Var output $(varlist)"
                - ${{ each cert in split(variables.varlist, ',')}}:
                  - task: PowerShell@2
                    displayName: "import ${{ cert }}"
                    inputs:
                      targetType: "inline"
                      script: |
                        Write-Host "Cert ${{ cert }}"
                        Write-Host "varlist $(varlist)"
```

The issue in the each loop with variables `- ${{ each cert in split(variables.varlist, ',')}}:`

the variable varlist contains the expected values in the `Write-Host "List $(varlist)"` but the `${{ cert }}` value contains the literal string of the variable set in th deploy stage

Log output:

```
Cert $[stageDependencies.StageA.mso.outputs['bla.varlist']]
varlist value1,value2
```

Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong? Based on the log output it just feels like a bug of some kind :/

Thanks for the answer in advanced!

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answers can give you some help.

Comment: I was a bit occupied with the weekend :D, but i'm back at it. Will update this post after trying out your suggestion!

Comment: May I know if you have any feedback about the method? I would like to confirm if it can work in your situation. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The each expression in YAML sample needs to read the Variable value at compile time. But the Cross Stage variable: **varlist** will expand at runtime.

In this case, the Each expression cannot obtain cross-stage variables when compiling. So it cannot successfully split the variable.

I would like to share a workaround to meet your requirement.

I suggest that you can split the Pipeline into two Pipelines(Stage A -> Pipeline One and Deploy Stage -> Pipeline two). The first Pipeline will use PowerShell script to pass the variable value to the parameter value in the Second Pipeline.

Here is an example:

Pipeline One:

```
stages:
  - stage: StageA
    displayName: "Stage A"
    pool: DefaultPool
    jobs:
      - job: StageA
        steps:
          - checkout: self

          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $token = "$(pat)"      
                $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{Projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineRunID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
                
                $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
                
                $JSON = "
                {
                  
                
                
                  `"resources`": {
                    `"repositories`": {
                      `"self`": {
                        `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  `"templateParameters`": {
                    `"varlist`":`"value1,value2`"
                  },
                
                
                
                }"
                
                
                $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

Pipeline Two

```
parameters:
  - name: varlist
    type: string

stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: "Deploy"

    jobs:
      - deployment: "Deploy"
        environment:
          name: "Production"
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
          tags: APP
        strategy:
          rolling:
            maxParallel: 100
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  displayName: "give output"
                  inputs:
                    targetType: "inline"
                    script: |
                      Write-Host "Var output ${{parameters.varlist}}"
                - ${{ each cert in split(parameters.varlist, ',')}}:
                  - task: PowerShell@2
                    displayName: "import ${{ cert }}"
                    inputs:
                      targetType: "inline"
                      script: |
                        Write-Host "Cert ${{ cert }}"
                        Write-Host "varlist ${{parameters.varlist}}"
```

The parameters value can be expand at compile time. And it can be splitted by each expression.

Comment: Went with this solution. Thank you! It's quite an ugly solution, but it was either this or rewrite all my tasks in Powershell to foreach loop it there.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `- ${{ each cert in split(variables.varlist, ',')}}:` is processed before a pipeline run. This operation `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varlist;isOutput=true]value1,value2"` is performed during a pipeline run. They just can not meet each other.